# Please check my code i wanted to make use of while where the condition must stop when user enter 0 in first input

Tags: java

Please check my code actually I wanted to try the while looping condition and if the user enters 0 for 1st number(n1) it must get out of the loop or else continue the calculation.

```java
class Test{
  public static void main(String []args)  {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
     float n1=sc.nextFloat();
     float n2=sc,nextFloat();
     float ans1=0;
     float ans2=0;
     float ans3=0;
     int count=0;

     while(n1!=0){
       ans1=n1+n2;
       ans2=n1*n2;
        count++;
     }

     ans3=ans1/ans2;
     System.out.println("Answer is "+ans3);
  }
}
```

**Actual output:**

```
Enter the number
2.0
3.0
4.0 
0
Answer is infinity
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Enter the number
2.0
3.0
Answer is 0.83
Enter the number 
4.0
5.0
Answer is 0.45
Enter the number
0
```

Comment: Well, you do not change the value of `n1` inside the loop, so your condition will be `true` forever. That seems to make the answer be `infinity`.

Comment: If ```n2 == 0``` then ```ans3=ans1/ans2``` will give you a divide by 0.

Comment: Check it for what? You get the input once; your loop will run forever. I'd recommend "playing computer" with a pencil and paper and actually understand what's happening (or, less preferable, step through it with a debugger). Being able to grok what's happening in code will be pretty important.

Comment: I wanted ans in form of expected output so what changes are needed to make it run as the expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code greatly by moving everything into the loop.  You can then put an `if` condition that `break`s out of the loop if `n1` is `0` and change the `loop` to an infinite loop until `break` is called.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
while (true){
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers (0 to quit):");

    float n1=sc.nextFloat();

    if (n1 == 0){
        break; //New part of the code
    }

    float n2=sc.nextFloat();
    float ans1=n1+n2;
    float ans2=n1*n2;
    float ans3=ans1 / ans2;
    System.out.println("Answer is "+ans3);
}
```

This way `0` will never be used in the calculation and `infinity` will never print since you won't divide by `0`.

**Example Run:**

```
Enter two numbers (0 to quit):
1 4
Answer is 1.25
Enter two numbers (0 to quit):
2 3
Answer is 0.8333333
Enter two numbers (0 to quit):
0
```

Comment: I don't think this falls into the realm of "hyper"; we'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your input inside of your while loop condition. This is because unless the user enters their first number as zero, your loop will run forever. Also you should do some sort of error checking for n2, since that can also not be zero. If n2 is zero, then ans2 is zero. Then ans3 will throw a divide by zero error. It should also be noted that you have an error declaring n2 in your original code due to using a `sc,nextFloat()` in stead of `sc.nextFloat()`

Here is some code to demonstrate what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
     float n1=sc.nextFloat();
     float n2=1;
     float ans1=0;
     float ans2=0;
     float ans3=0;
     int count=0;
      while(n1!=0)
     {
       n2=sc.nextFloat();
       while(n2 == 0)
       {
         System.out.println("Second number can not be zero. Enter a new number");
         n2=sc.nextFloat();
       }//End while loop for n2==0
       ans1=n1+n2;
       ans2=n1*n2;
       count++;
       ans3=ans1/ans2;
       System.out.println("Answer is "+ans3);
       System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
       n1=sc.nextFloat();
     }//End while loop for n1
  }//End main
```

I personally do not like the use of break statements, as I believe it inhibits bad practice/poor design of loop conditions. For most cases, you should be able to set a loop condition to break out without iterating more than necessary. This is mere opinion however, and mine matches what my professors have told me.

Comment: The use of `break` and `continue` is dependent on the problem being solved: Code should express intent as concisely and clearly as possible; that may (or may not) involve `break`/`continue`. Dogmatic proscriptions don't serve anyone very well.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a very simple problem, and I hope that you are able to solve it yourself, here I try to explain the problem to you and suggest a solution:

You want your input to be repeated until 0 is entered. You already know the concept of the `while` loop, as you can see. You can now use it to repeat your entire input and calculation until the user enters 0:

```
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
float n1 = 1;
while(n1 != 0){
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
    [...]    
}
```

Go through your program line by line from top to bottom to understand, what you are doing: 1. Create a scanner, 2. Define n1 = 1, 3. Repeat the following part as long as n1 != 0 ...

Then, as you mentioned, you want your executable to terminate instantly when n1 = 0, not just at the end of the code in the `while` loop.
For this purpose, you can use the `break` condition: Its jumping directly to the end of the loop, in your case, the end of your code.

I also want you to know the `continue` command which is directly going to the next iteration of the loop. This is for example helpful if someone enters invalid data.

You could use it the following:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
float n1 = 1;
while(n1 != 0){ //loop until n1 == 0
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
    n1=sc.nextFloat();
    if(n1 == 0){ //if n1 equals 0
        break; // goes to the end of the loop
    }
    float n2=sc.nextFloat();
    if(n2 == 0){ //division by zero
        System.out.println("Division by zero, try again!");
        continue; //goes to the beginning of the loop again
    }

    float ans1=0;
    float ans2=0;
    float ans3=0;
    int count=0;

    ans1=n1+n2;
    ans2=n1*n2;
    count++;


    ans3=ans1/ans2;
    System.out.println("Answer is "+ans3);
}
```